# When google sheets api quota restores?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits  --  limit is 500 requests per 100 secconds

Can anybody tell me this 100 secconds for restore quotas starts when I make first request of 500 available? Or it restores every 100 secconds from Unix time beginning and no matter when I start to use it?

Thanks a lot for help! Best regards, Oleh.

Comment: It's not something that I have a of experience with, but the second option seems unlikely. It would have the effect of placing every user on the same quota timetable which would be a nightmare.

Comment: The way it works is more similar to the first one that the second as @Tedinoz has already pointed out. Are you having problems with the requests as right now? Have you tried to space out your request or batching them together with the correct endpoint?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ettension! Yes, I use batch methods. No, I have no problems right now, but I just start to make new program and need to know how to make it correctly. Thanks, I'll try first one and I think that will not be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tedinoz has said, is pretty infeasible to synchronize a global quota reset based on Unix time. So probably the actual way google is handling this is more of an user based approach seeing how many request are you making in a given amount of time.